# How to delete an object from the nested Array using underscore JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have nested array's and need to delete the object based on condition.

Array:

```
grouplist: [
    {
        name: "one",
        optionlist: [
            {
                optionitem: "green"
            },
            {
                optionitem: "red"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "two",
        optionlist: [
            {
                optionitem: "yellow"
            },
            {
                optionitem: "red"
            },
            {
                optionitem: "blue"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "three",
        optionlist: [
            {
                optionitem: "green"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "four",
        optionlist: [
            {
                optionitem: "blue"
            },
            {
                optionitem: "red"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

If the optionItem color is green, then I need to remove it completely from my array object.

This is what I have tried.

```
var returnedData = _.filter(grouplist, function(n) { 
    return _.some(n.optionlist, function(option){ 
        return option.optionitem!= "green";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var returnedData = _.filter(grouplist, function(n){ 
  var containsGreen = _.some(n.optionlist, function(option){ 
    return option.optionitem === "green";
  })
  return !containsGreen;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var returnedData = _.reject(grouplist, function(n){ 
  return _.some(n.optionlist, function(option){ 
    return option.optionitem === "green";
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `filter` or `_.filter` is that you're creating a *new* array. If you want to simply remove an object from the existing array without creating a new one, here's a simple vanilla JS way of doing that in the same number of lines of code:

```
for (var i = 0, l = grouplist.length; i < l; i++) {
  var foundGreen = grouplist[i].optionlist.some(function (el) {
      return el.optionitem === 'green'; 
  });
  if (foundGreen) grouplist.splice(i, 1); i--; l--;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ar11w38/1/)

Comment: It's not a good idea to remove items from an array when iterating over it from first to last (example 1) as items move in the array and will be ignored e.g. if you add 'green' to the second item in the array then the array will still contain that item. When removing items you can iterate from last to first and that will work.